# Precision not allowed in integer format specifier

Tags: python-3.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/akb/pytorch_learning/chap4_dogsandcats", line 110, in 
epoch_loss, epoch_accuracy = fit(epoch,model,train_data_loader,phase='training')
File "/home/akb/pytorch_learning/chap4_dogsandcats", line 103, in fit
print(f'{phase} loss is {loss:{5}.{2}} and {phase} accuracy is {running_correct}/{len(data_loader.dataset)}{accuracy:{10}.{4}}')
File "/home/akb/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 337, in format
return self.item().format(format_spec)
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier
```

i am getting this error in sublime text 3 with CPU, and why does it work fine with GPU. anyone could help?

Comment: Can you make an example? MOre detailed explanation about your code would help others to answer more easily.

Comment: hi @Progressive, actually i am learning pytorch, book named deeplearning by pytroch(Vishnu Subramanian), while learning line by line i stuck in this problem ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier). i am sharing github of this book. it may help you to find out the solution of this problem

Comment: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch/blob/master/Chapter05/Understanding%20Convolutions%20and%20building%20an%20MNIST%20image%20classifier.ipynb

Comment: Either `loss` or `accuracy` is an `int`, but you are using precision in your format string, which is limited to `float`s.